# Is it possible to limit who on an AD domain can join computers to the domain?

Tags: windows, domain, active-directory

We are trying to prevent users from willy-nilly joining VMs and outside machines to our domain. The default is any user can join up to 10 machines. Is there a way to limit this to only Account Operators, Domain Admins, and Enterprise Admins?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go into your Domain Security Policy>Local Policy>User Rights Assignment and change the "Add workstations to domain" to just the groups you want.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're looking for is referenced in these two MSKB articles:

- [Default limit to number of workstations a user can join to the domain](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243327)
- [Domain Users Cannot Join Workstation or Server to a Domain](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251335) (where to look)

The first article gives the details on where to go in Adsiedit.msc to change the default value (Domain NC, pick the right item, Properties, view ms-DS-MachineAccountQuota, edit attribute to change the value).

I've also seen a mention that there's a Group Policy under Default Domain Controllers Policy\User Rights Assignment but I'm not at a good spot to go digging for it to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/220933-36-restrict-computer-domain-join-domain):

There is a group policy that can change who has the right to add machines to the domain.
I'm not in front of a server at the moment but if I remember correctly this can be changed easily.

KCotreau's answer shows the group policy changes I mention in detail.