# Prevent disabled computer accounts from joining the domain

Tags: active-directory

in our company we have some servers that are not centrally managed. I would like to clean up in the OU where these servers are located by disabling accounts that do not match certain criteria. While testing that I discovered that I can bypass the disabled state by unjoining and rejoining the domain.

Is there any way to prevent disabled computer accounts from joining the domain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can limit this by using group policy.
If you have a group policy which doesn't allow users to join the domain, then you will basically reduce the risk of disabled computer leaving and re-joining the domain.

As mentioned in the article I'm adding here, the lowest permissions for joining a computer to the domain would be an "Authenticated user"
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/27490147-f922-49d0-b105-4cc0a10c9324/what-is-the-minimum-privilege-to-join-client-pc-to-ad-domain?forum=winserverDS

This is probably the answer you're looking for:
[Is it possible to limit who on an AD domain can join computers to the domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/290762/is-it-possible-to-limit-who-on-an-ad-domain-can-join-computers-to-the-domain/290765)

Edit: Also this should be useful - restricting who can remove a computer from a domain:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/180192-can-i-prevent-users-from-removing-pc-s-from-a-domain